# Magento 2 : Add product to cart programmatically does not populate quote item id in validate method

Tags: magento2.2, addtocart, programmatically

How to add product to cart programmatically in Magento 2.2.0 ?

I have tried below code but when I do not get Quote item id in **Validate** method of below file.

```
\Magento\AdvancedSalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product.php
```

**Code:**

```
protected $formKey;   
protected $cart;
protected $product;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
array $data = []) {
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->product = $product;      
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
 { 
  $productId = 32;
  $params = array(
                'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                'product' => $productId, 
                'qty'   => 2                
            );              

    $_product = $this->product->load($productId);  

    $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);

    $this->cart->save();
 }
```

**Sales Rule Validate Method Code:**

**File:** `\Magento\AdvancedSalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product.php`

**Method:**

```
public function validate(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model)
    {
        //@todo reimplement this method when is fixed MAGETWO-5713
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        $product = $model->getProduct();
        if (!$product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($model->getProductId());
        }

        if ($model instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item) {
            die($model->getItemId()); //NULL
```

Thanks

Comment: protected $formKey; protected $cart; protected $product; public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey, \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, array $data = []) { $this->formKey = $formKey; $this->cart = $cart; $this->product = $product; parent::__construct($context); } public function execute() { $productId = 32; $params = array( 'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(), 'product' => $productId, 'qty' => 2, 'price' => 20 ); $_product = $this->product->load($productId); $this->c

Comment: @kapil, did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out, I will post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

you can used this code.

```
protected $formKey;   
protected $cart;
protected $product;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
array $data = []) {
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->product = $product;      
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
 { 
  $productId = 32;
  $params = array(
                'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                'product' => $productId, 
                'qty'   => 2                
            );              

    $_product = $this->product->load($productId);  

    $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);

    $this->cart->save();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, But I do not get Quote item id in \Magento\AdvancedSalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product.php Validate method , when I use above code.

Comment: If you have new requirement with this, please ask question according to that.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class AddProducttocart extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
{
    /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey
     */
    protected $formKey;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $params = array(
                'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                'product' =>1,//product Id
                'qty'   =>1,//quantity of product
                'price' =>20 //product price
            );
            $this->_redirect("checkout/cart/add/form_key/", $params);
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```